# Traversing through a linked list: while(ptr!=NULL) vs while(ptr->next!=NULL)?

Tags: c++, while-loop, linked-list

Defining a memory cell by

```
struct node {
    int item;
    node *next;
};
```

and assuming `ptr` is pointing to a linked list, is there a difference between putting `while(ptr!=NULL)` *vs* `while(ptr->next!=NULL)` to loop through the list until reaching the null pointer?

Comment: You will need to write `struct node *next` inside your `struct`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You are right. With C++ it works well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`while(ptr->next!=NULL)` won't loop through your last node.

By the time you get to your last node, `ptr->next` will be null, and it will get out of the `while` loop

Comment: ... which is useful if (and only if) the last node is a sentinal.

Comment: @SteveJessop well put. Just for sake of information, if OP is not familiar with it: a sentinel node is a dummy node that can be added after the last node

Comment: Also `while(ptr->next!=NULL)` will crash when the list is empty (you are dereferencing `ptr` without checking it for NULL first).

Answer (score 6):

`while(ptr != NULL)` will iterate on all your linked list when `while(ptr->next != NULL)` will skip the last element.

The second solution is useful when you want to access your last node to add a new element at the end of the list for example.